# I would like to know how you can use in Java 8

Tags: for-loop, foreach, filter, java-8, java-stream

I would like to know how you can use in Java 8 .
I want to use the stream for an existing sentence .

```
List<t> selected;
List<t> filtered;

for (int count = 0; count < selected.size(); count++) {
                if(!StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(selected.get(count).getBasic(), "1")) {

            for (int t = 0; t < filtered.size(); t++) {
                if (StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(selected.get(count).getTitle(), filtered.get(t).getTitle())) {
                    selected.set(count, filtered.get(t));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to specify your problem a little better. I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're modifying the existing `List`, you should use `List.replaceAll` instead of the Stream API. However Stream API could be used as a replacement of the inner loop:

```
selected.replaceAll(sel ->
    StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(sel.getBasic(), "1") ? sel :
      filtered.stream()
              .filter(fil -> StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(sel.getTitle(), fil.getTitle())
              .findFirst()
              .orElse(sel)
);
```

Note that it's a little bit different comparing to your code as your inner loop does not short-circuit unlike `.findFirst()`: it continues search in `filtered` list even after the match is found. If it's intentional, you should replace `.findFirst()` with `.reduce((a, b) -> b)` in my solution to get the same result.